# How to connect two websites together one website just used php while the other used codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to connect my websites together like for example I put a link on my other website to got to the other website, I want it to automatically be logged in as I am still logged in on my other website.

`aside.php` on my main website:

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <a href="https:localhost/academy_lms/login" target="_blank" class="nav-link <?php if($pageid==19){ echo 'active';}?>">
          <i class="nav-icon"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></i>
          <p>
            ACADEMY
           
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
```

`login.php` on my other website:

```
        <form action="<?php echo site_url('login/validate_login/user'); ?>" method="post" id="sign_up">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login-ID"><?php echo site_phrase('AgentID'); ?></label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-text bg-white" for="AgentID"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
              <input type="number" name="AgentID" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo site_phrase('AgentID'); ?>" aria-label="<?php echo site_phrase('AgentID'); ?>" aria-describedby="<?php echo site_phrase('AgentID'); ?>" id="login-ID" required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login-password"><?php echo site_phrase('password'); ?></label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-text bg-white" for="password"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo site_phrase('password'); ?>" aria-label="<?php echo site_phrase('password'); ?>" aria-describedby="<?php echo site_phrase('password'); ?>" id="login-password" required>
            </div>
            <a class="text-muted text-12px fw-500 float-end" href="<?php echo site_url('home/forgot_password'); ?>"><?php echo site_phrase('forgot_password'); ?>?</a>
          </div>

          <?php if(get_frontend_settings('recaptcha_status')): ?>
            <div class="form-group mt-4 mb-0">
              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo get_frontend_settings('recaptcha_sitekey'); ?>"></div>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn red radius-10 mt-4 w-100"><?php echo site_phrase('login'); ?></button>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group mt-4 mb-0 text-center">
            <?php echo site_phrase('do_not_have_an_account'); ?>?
            <a class="text-15px fw-700" style="color: #FD6161" href="<?php echo site_url('home/sign_up') ?>"><?php echo site_phrase('sign_up'); ?></a>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: if the two sites share a common domain ( ie 2 sub-domains) then this should be reasonably straightforward but two distinct and separate sites needs something like `single sign on` and is way more complicated than anything shown in the question

Comment: if both hosted. Just use `<a>` with `www.site2.com` and in the second `www.site1.com` , if you're not passing any sessions